# How to update value in setInterval function

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I used `setInterval` function that **decreases** the `time` value by every second to develop the **timer** In **`ReactJS`**.

And when I clicked the `RESET` button before the `time` value is 0, I expected the `time` value to update back to **10 seconds**, but it didn't work in the `setInterval` function.

How can I modify the `time` value which updated outside the setInterval function to even **within the setInterval function**?

---

Here's the code that I experiment with.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function Timer() {
  let time = 10;
  const [timeText, setTimeText] = useState(time);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

  const handleReset = () => {
    if (timerOn) {
      /* This statement can not update the time value
      within the Interval function. */
      time = 10;
      return;
    }
    setTimerOn(true);
    let timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeText(time);
      time--;
      if (time < 0) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        setTimerOn(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timeText}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>RESET</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

---

Here's the desired result:

- If `RESET` button was clicked when the time value is greater than 1, it changes back to 10.

Current result:

- [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x1Eg.gif)

[enter image description here][1]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400851/can-not-update-state-inside-setinterval-in-react-hook/68249809#68249809) is related, but it doesn't answer my question of how to update the `time` value within the setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code again, because my first comment was actually wrong:

I made a few changes in your code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Timer() {
  // removed the const, you dont need it
  const [timeText, setTimeText] = useState(10);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

  const handleReset = () => {
    if (timerOn) {
      // set the state here directly
      setTimeText(10);
      return;
    }
    setTimerOn(true);
    let timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      // update the state by subtract 1 from it.
      // we need to wrap this in a function, because setState() is async
      setTimeText((state) => state - 1);
      if (timeText < 0) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        setTimerOn(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timeText}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>RESET</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with reference. Inside `setInterval` closure variable `time` refers to a different variable than `time` at the beginning of `handleReset`. After first rerender variable `time` is created again, and this second version is used by the rest of the code, but `setInterval` still uses the same one variable from the beginning. Check out this example

```js
export function App(props) {
  let time = 10;
  const [timeText1, setTimeText1] = useState(time);
  const [timeText2, setTimeText2] = useState(time);
  
  const handleReset1 = () => {
    let timerInterval1 = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeText1(time);
      
      time--;
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleReset2 = () => {
    let timerInterval2 = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeText2(time);
      
      time++;
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timeText1}</h1>
      <h1>{timeText2}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleReset1}>RESET1</button>
      <button onClick={handleReset2}>RESET2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Press first `RESET` and wait for rerender. Then press second `RESET`. Both setIntervals use `time`, but it is completely different time, because of the rerender between them.
Try to press both of them at the same time, they get stuck, because since no-rerender between them, they will use the same `time` variable.

You could make it work, by assuring that there will be only one `time`  that changes only value, but not `reference` (even after rerender). You can achieve it by using `useRef`. However, keep in mind it's more for educational(?) purpose than production-ready code.

```js
export function App() {
  const time = useRef(10)
  const [timeText, setTimeText] = useState(time.current);
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

  const handleReset = () => {
    if (timerOn) {
      /* This statement can not update the time value
      within the Interval function. */
      time.current = 10;
      return;
    }
    setTimerOn(true);
    let timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeText(time.current);
      time.current--;
      if (time.current < 0) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        setTimerOn(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timeText}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>RESET</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Approach of `@MoreTags` is a lot better for this kind of problem, but I wanted to show why it works the way it does.